# Is there a way in Python to calculate one time as a percentage of another?

Tags: python

I am quite new to coding, but I am currently trying to figure out whether it is possible to take one time and see what percentage it is of a longer time.

For example, what percentage of 24:53:37 is 1:59:15? (HH:min:sec)

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried so far? In which form is your input provided? Have you considered just converting to seconds and then dividing the seconds?

Comment: The best way would be to turn them both into milliseconds/ticks/epochs, then you just have two numbers (you know how to get the percentage with just two numbers)

Comment: The answer to the question you asked is 'yes'. Now you have to show what you have tried and we can tell you why it's not working.

Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for information on how to ask a question that will lead to a good answer.

Comment: FYI, the values you have aren't *points* in time, but *durations* between two points in time. ISO 8601 would write those as `H24M53S37` and `H1M59S15` to avoid ambiguity. The `datetime` module provides the `timedelta` type to represent durations.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service, nor is it meant to provide personalized guides and tutorials. See: [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
from datetime import timedelta

hh, mm, ss = map(int, '24:53:37'.split(':'))
t1 = timedelta(hours=hh, minutes=mm, seconds=ss)
hh, mm, ss = map(int, '1:59:15'.split(':'))
t2 = timedelta(hours=hh, minutes=mm, seconds=ss)
percentage = t2/t1
```

Comment: Thank you, that is very helpful!